# In sql.executemany(... syntax error near '('

Tags: python, mysql, pymssql, executemany

I'm trying to execute the following code in python, but it results in `syntax error near '('` error for `executemany(..)`. When I remove te names from `sql` and just write `%s` it also results in the error that `there are more placeholders thant the variables`
does anyone know how I can fix it?

```
upInfo ={"aa": "aaa","bb": "bbb","cc": "ccc"}
sql = 'UPDATE table SET a=  %(aa)s WHERE b= %(bb)s and c= %(cc)s'
con = pymssql.connect(...)
con.autocommit(True)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.executemany(sql, upInfo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is `executemany()`, it should be a list of dictionaries:

```
upInfo = [{"aa": "aaa", "bb": "bbb", "cc": "ccc"}]
```

Or, use a regular `execute()`:

```
cur.execute(sql, upInfo)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works, but I'm passing an object to my python file at a time. since it is only one dictionary, I'd rather not to deal with it as a list. Do you know any other safe way rather than executemany which works the same way?

Comment: @user4103576 ok, but why not use a regular `execute()` here? Thanks.

Comment: Since it is [not safe](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-logging.html) I'd rather use placeholders

Comment: `execute(stmt, {"aa": "aaa", "bb": "bbb", "cc": "ccc"})` is as safe as `executemany(stmt,[{"aa": "aaa", "bb": "bbb", "cc": "ccc"}])`. Both use [prepared statements and will bind values](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id16). Or am I wrong ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I didn't know that `execute` has the option of placeholders like `executemany`. Thanks for the answer